# Error when generating meta model code with JOOQ from SYBASE DB

Tags: java, sap-ase, jooq

I have this error when trying to generate the meta model with JOOQ:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select [SYS].[SYSUSER].[user_name] from [SYS].[SYSUSER]]; SYS.SYSUSER not found.
```

It's probably because the user does not have administration rights.
Can JOOQ generate metamodel code from create statements? 
I don't have another user. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Sybase SQL Anywhere is this? Or are you using Sybase ASE?

Comment: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3 - is it because of the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong database as understood by jOOQ, as documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/manual/META/Configuration/

Note, how the documentation states:

```xml
<!-- The database dialect from jooq-meta. Available dialects are
     named org.util.[database].[database]Database. Known values are:

     org.jooq.util.ase.ASEDatabase
     [...]
     org.jooq.util.sybase.SybaseDatabase

     You can also provide your own org.jooq.util.Database implementation
     here, if your database is currently not supported -->
     <name>org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase</name>
```

The SQL you've mentioned seems to be from the `SybaseDatabase` class (which corresponds to Sybase SQL Anywhere), whereas you should use the `ASEDatabase` class instead, generating calls to `sp_help`

Comment: Thanks. You were right about that. However, it does not find any tables apparently(INFO: Generating schemata      : Total: 0). I can see the schema in squirrel client with this user. Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jOOQ? Did you specify the `<inputSchema/>` element, as documented further down?

Comment: 2.3.1 and yes, I do specify the inputSchema. It worked with mysql, I started from there. I also tried with the schema name in uppercase.

Comment: Do you get any log output (e.g. by using log4j with DEBUG level with this sample [log4j.xml file](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-test/src/log4j.xml))? What does this query yield: `SELECT * FROM SYSUSERS`? Note, you can also use the [jOOQ user group](http://groups.google.com/group/jooq-user) for support requests

Comment: well, it does make that query and it returns a result of 759 entries(759 record(s) truncated...). My user is not on the list.

Comment: Is the value specified in `<inputSchema/>` the owner of the schema you want to generate? If it is, then I'm afraid, I'm at the end of my Sybase ASE knowledge... Maybe you could ask a separate Stack Overflow question for that problem?

Comment: Hmm...seems I confused schema with catalog. My bad...not much sybase knowledge.